# How to create a new XCode project from an existing c/c++ code space

Tags: xcode, xcode-template

How to create a new XCode project from an existing c/c++ code space?
What type of project I should pick from XCode project template?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the existing code has a build system like Make or CMake etc., you probably want to use the "External Build System" template under "Other" in the projects pane. If you want to incorporate the existing code into a new application/framework/etc., create a template for the type of product you want to eventually build, then add a "Run Script" build phase to call your external build system.

MacResearch.org has a [tutorial](http://www.macresearch.org/tutorial-introducing-xcode-30-organizer) on using the Xcode Organizer to build external targets that you may also find useful.